# Insert text into text field with python, for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

So i am working on a small project that is primarily web scraping. I have one small problem though. I need to check if a specific element of the website has a background color of red, or green. To be able to see the element, i need to insert some text into a text field first... How would i go about that?

I am scraping with BeautifulSoup right now.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the exact code would help us to solve the problem.

If you want to interact with the webpage, you should use packages like selenium. That will help you add a text in the textfield. After performing this operation, you may see the clasfs/style of the required item if changed.

Comment: This should be stated in the comments, not as an answer/solution

Comment: I have looked into Selenium, but i need to download some drivers for the browser i want to use... The different sites i use to check virusses, calls thouse drivers out as virusses... Is it safe?

Comment: You download the driver once from a reliable website. (official website) and use it

Comment: Alright thank you! I will try and get that to work.